# how to unzip an uploaded zip file using spring in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am uploading zip folder from screen and I am sending it to contoller using MultipartFile.I am trying to extract the uploaded folder and saving that extracted folder in some specific location..I tried but I am not getting....Can anyone suggest me?
here is my code

```
 public  String test(
                @RequestParam("datafile") MultipartFile file
    { 

    String source =file.getOriginalFilename();

    //source variable will containthe value as "zip_Folder.zip";
            String destination = "D:\\destination";

            try {
                 ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
                 zipFile.extractAll(destination);

            } catch (ZipException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly the error?? or `extractAll` is not working properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Required [zip4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j) and [Apache Commons-IO](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io) dependencies:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String add(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    /**
     * save file to temp
     */
    File zip = File.createTempFile(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "temp");
    FileOutputStream o = new FileOutputStream(zip);
    IOUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), o);
    o.close();

    /**
     * unizp file from temp by zip4j
     */
    String destination = "D:\\destination";
    try {
         ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zip);
         zipFile.extractAll(destination);
    } catch (ZipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        /**
         * delete temp file
         */
        zip.delete();
    }

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

As addition to that, the best is to place constants like "D:\destination" in properties file and inject by [@Value](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html)

```
@Value("${destination.dir}")
private String destination;
```

Comment: Super ...Thank you  so much

Comment: nice answer..+1...zip4j is much easier than java util zip

Comment: not working on linux environment.. not able to unzip. I even given all permission to particular folder

Comment: Hello, Is there a way to get the unzipped bytes without saving it to the driver ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
 java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;`

worked for me

example

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, In that link we are mentioning the full path like INPUT_ZIP_FILE = "C:\\MyFile.zip"...But in my case I am having only MyFile.zip...So It is throwing exception